# How to save the filed as pointer in parse knowing the object id in another class (table)?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Assume, If I have a two tables, let it be table 1 and table 2. I would like to save the object id of  a data in table 1 to table 2. How to do this?. This is how I tried to get the object of the table 1 data with its object id.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("objWithId", function(request, response) {
  var Table1 = Parse.Object.extend("Table1");
  var query = Parse.Query(Table1);
  query.equalTo(id, request.params.dataId);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```

But, I get the error as : TypeError: Cannot call method 'equalTo' of undefined

Comment: You are missing a `new` when creating the query. It should be `var query = new Parse.Query(Table1)`

Comment: Don't know. How I have missed it. I have struggled with it for a day. You saved my day. Thanks...